# Django mock patch doesn't work as I expect

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, redis

Summary : I am doing an experiment to try to create a simple mock to replace redis. What I'm trying to do should be obvious from the code. Short version is, the mock doesn't work - It's still going to redis and creating keys.

tests.py:

```
from django.test import TestCase
import mock
from redis_mock.simple_redis_mock import redisMockGetRedis, redisMockFlushDB
from account.util import get_redis

class SimpleTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        redisMockFlushDB()

    @mock.patch("account.util.get_redis", redisMockGetRedis)
    def test_redis(self):
        key = "hello123"
        value = "world123"
        r = get_redis()
        r.set(key, value)
        value2 = r.get(key)
        self.assertEqual(value, value2)
```

util.py:

```
import redis

REDIS_HOST = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_DEFAULT_DB = 0

def get_redis():
    print "account.util.get_redis"
    return redis.StrictRedis(
        REDIS_HOST, 
        REDIS_PORT, 
        REDIS_DEFAULT_DB
    )
```

simple_redis_mock.py:

```
"""
A simple mock for Redis. Just mocks set, get and expire commands.
"""

class SimpleRedisMockDB:
    db = {}

def redisMockFlushDB():
    """
    Helper function to flush the RedisMock db between test runs
    """
    print "redisMockFlushDB"
    SimpleRedisMock.db = {}

class SimpleRedisMock:
    def get(self, key):
        val = None
        try:
            val = SimpleRedisMockDB.db[key]
        except:
            pass
        print "SimpleRedisMock get(" + str(key) + "):" + str(val)
        return val

    def set(self, key, val):
        print "SimpleRedisMock set(" + str(key) + "," + str(val) +")"
        SimpleRedisMockDB.db[key] = val

    def expire(self, key):
        pass


def redisMockGetRedis():
    print "redisMockGetRedis"
    return SimpleRedisMock()
```

Now, what I expect is that when I run my test, no redis keys are set. Here's what actually happens:

```
twang$ redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> del hello123
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> exit
twang$ ./manage.py test account
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
redisMockFlushDB
account.util.get_redis
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
twang$ redis-cli
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> get hello123
"world123"
```

Simple question : Why isn't mock.patch doing what I expect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python mock patch doesn't work as expected for public method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987973/python-mock-patch-doesnt-work-as-expected-for-public-method)

Answer (score 12):

The link

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch

helped me understand better how to go about patching function calls in python.

Comment: This made it "click" for me +1

Answer (score 8):

Patch only mocks out the object in the location that you have patched it. A quick bit of example code should help explain what is going on.

```
from mock import Mock, patch
import unittest

from patch_code import anotherfunc, thefunc

print 'Function imported', thefunc

class SomeTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('patch_code.thefunc', Mock())
    def test_method(self):
        anotherfunc()
        print 'Inside test method', thefunc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

And the code under test is just two functions:

```
def thefunc():
    pass

def anotherfunc():
    print 'Inside code under test', thefunc
```

Running that test gives the following output

```
Function imported <function thefunc at 0xb740e614>
Inside code under test <Mock id='3071597132'>
Inside test method <function thefunc at 0xb740e614>
```

You can clearly see that the only place that patch has mocked 'thefunc' is in the code under test.

If you want to test the function `get_redis` without causing any side effects then you should mock out `account.util.redis.StrictRedis` and assert that it was called with the correct arguments.

If you want to test functions that **use** `get_redis` then you should mock out `get_redis` and, import the function that is using get_redis, and call **that** function in your test.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of importing `get_redis`, try `import util and call util.get_redis()`.

Comment: This worked for me but I still don't understand why it worked... ◑﹏◐