# Python mock patch doesn't work as expected for public method

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking, magicmock

I'm trying to patch a public method for my flask application but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code in `mrss.feed_burner`

```
def get_feed(env=os.environ):
   return 'something'
```

And this is how I use it

```
@app.route("/feed")
    def feed():
        mrss_feed = get_feed(env=os.environ)
        response = make_response(mrss_feed)
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/xml"

        return response
```

And this is my test which it's not parsing.

```
def test_feed(self):
    with patch('mrss.feed_burner.get_feed', new=lambda: '<xml></xml>'):
        response = self.app.get('/feed')
        self.assertEquals('<xml></xml>', response.data)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you're not patching in the right namespace. See [where_to_patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) documentation for `unittest.mock.patch`.

Essentially, you're patching the definition of `get_feed()` in `mrss.feed_burner` but your view handler `feed()` already has a reference to the original `mrss.feed_burner.get_feed()`. To solve this problem, you need to patch the reference in your view file.

Based on your usage of `get_feed` in your view function, I assume you're importing `get_feed` like so

view_file.py

```
from mrss.feed_burner import get_feed
```

If so, you should be patching `view_file.get_feed` like so:

```
def test_feed(self):
    with patch('view_file.get_feed', new=lambda: '<xml></xml>'):
        ...
```